# Finding the device model and make

Tags: java, android

How do I find the make and model of an Android device?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[android.os.Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) contains properties you are interested in.

`Build.MODEL`, `Build.PRODUCT` and `Build.MANUFACTURER` should give you the info you need. They are all String objects.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) should help.

`Build.DEVICE;`

`Build.BRAND;`

etc...

Comment: For example if I'm using a HTC Legend? How do I find it out?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact results will be, run it on an HTC Legend (or get someone else to) and find out!

Comment: Class names without package names are not very helpful. ageektrapped did better here.